# how can I use if condition with multiple string condition

Tags: php, session

I am developing a users role application so I need to have User Type in Oder to set user role

```
$user_role = $_SESSION["user_role"];

if ($user_role != "Administrator" || $user_role != "Manager") {
    header("location: login.php");
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I guess you can use this.

```
if ($user_role == "Administrator" || $user_role == "Manager") {
  header("location: mainpage.php");
} else {
  header("location: login.php");
}
```

Comment: _I guess you can use this_ Why guess and why should they?

Comment: He just wants to differ from user with a role and other users. If i understand it aright this is the target.

Answer (score 4):

This condition will always be true, because `$user_role` can't be two things at once.

```
if ($user_role != "Administrator" || $user_role != "Manager") {
```

In other words

- If `$user_role == 'Administrator'` then `$user_role != 'Manager'`, and
- If `$user_role == 'Manager'` then `$user_role != 'Administrator'`.

Consider using `&&` or `in_array` instead.

```
if ($user_role != "Administrator" && $user_role != "Manager") {
// or
if (!in_array($user_role, ["Administrator", "Manager"])) {
```